# The deletion of the network endpoint group failed. Error: Request failed with unknown error

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm having this error when I try to delete a `Network Endpoint Group` on Google Cloud Platform console. How to solve that?

> The deletion of the network endpoint group failed. Error: Request
> failed with unknown error

Answer (score 1):

The error message you receive makes me think it could be a browser/cache related issue, I would first try using a Chrome / Firefox incognito in order to rule out this.

If that doesn't work, then try the following command on your [Cloud Shell](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?cloudshell=true&_ga=2.118841609.16629695.1604337990-1233280822.1602106851):

gcloud beta compute network-endpoint-groups delete ENDPOINT_NAME --project [PROJECT-ID](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like regional NEG cannot be deleted using the Cloud Console.
As Frank suggested using the [Cloud Shell](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?cloudshell=true) to delete it worked for me.

List the network endpoint groups and their regions:

```
gcloud beta compute network-endpoint-groups list
```

This should output the following:

```
NAME          LOCATION      ENDPOINT_TYPE       SIZE
my-neg        europe-west6  SERVERLESS          0
```

Then delete it with specifying the correct region:

```
gcloud beta compute network-endpoint-groups delete my-neg --region=europe-west6
```

If you specify an incorrect region gcloud will just respond with a "resource not found" error.